# Change method call for specific object

Tags: c#, reflection

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39973972/1870760) question got me wondering if something similar is possible using the dark reflection ways of C#.

Say I have this code:

```
public class Foo
    {
        public void FooPrint() // can't change this implementation
        {
            Console.Write("Foo");
        }
    }

public class Bar
{
    public Foo foo = new Foo();
    public Bar()
    {
        //do some reflection magic with member foo here ?
    }

    public void FooPrintRewritten()
    {
        Console.Write("Haha, only for Bar.foo."); 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo a = new Foo();
        a.FooPrint(); // should still print "Foo"

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo.FooPrint(); // should print "Haha, only for Bar.foo."
    }
}
```

Is what I ask for in the inlined comments in any way possible? Is there a way to re-bind a method call to another method for only a specific variable?

<sub>Yes I know this is ridiculous, no this shouldn't ever be used in production code. This is for the sake of curiosity.</sub>

Comment: I think typemock is doing something similar but from what I know it plays with the IL code..... You can also use the idea of interceptors but you will have to have some control over the creation of `Foo`

Comment: If `Foo` is an interface, then yes (supply a different implementation), if `Foo` derives from `MarshalByRefObject`, then yes (you can use a transparent proxy), if callers don't need the exact type `Foo` but merely something that can behave as one, then yes (supply a user-defined implicit conversion), if they really positively need a `Foo`, as-is, then no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have suggested ways in which you can achieve what you want on a functional level, which is arguably the sane thing to do, but I'll tackle the question directly: can this be done changing no code in the question except the implementation of `Bar.Bar()`, keeping `Bar.foo` of type `Foo` and changing nothing about `Foo`?

The answer is no. You cannot change the method table for a single object, which is basically what you're asking for here. The method table is part of the type, not the instance. If an expression `f` is of type `Foo`, and `FooPrint` is a non-virtual method of `Foo`, then the call `f.FooPrint()` will always resolve to `Foo.FooPrint`. Even worse, the compiler might choose to inline the call since that's obviously a safe optimization<sup>*</sup>. Where are your dark reflection ways now?

The only way to achieve this is to convince the compiler that calls to `Foo.FooPrint` should be treated specially, taking the instance into consideration. There are a few ways of doing so:

- `Foo.FooPrint` could be made a delegate. The targets of a delegate call are specific per instance of the delegate.
- `Foo.FooPrint` could be made a virtual, abstract or interface method. All of these are resolved based on the runtime type of the instance. Simply derive a class from `Foo` and away you go.
- `Foo` could inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`. An MBRO, as it's commonly called, is treated specially by the jitter since (as the name implies) calls may need to be marshalled back. In particular, if `Foo` was an MBRO, you could create a [`RealProxy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy) for it that will cough up a transparent proxy that resembles a real, actual `Foo` in almost all ways, right down to `GetType()`, except that you get to choose how calls are actually handled.

All of these approaches are used by various mocking/interceptor/proxy libraries, all of them require *some* change to `Foo`. The only approaches that require no (textual) change to `Foo` are those that rewrite the IL involved, like PostSharp or Microsoft Fakes, but I'd consider that cheating for purposes of this question.

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically, the C# standard says nothing about either method tables or permissible ways of inlining since those are implementation details, but it does say that `Foo.FooPrint` is always resolved in only one way without considering the instance (except that it must not be `null`).

Answer (score 1):

What about this, with still the same usage:

```
public class Wrapper : Foo
{
    public new void FooPrint()
    {
        Console.Write("Haha, only for Bar.foo.");
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Wrapper foo = new Wrapper();        
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add, having no access to `Foo`'s implementation.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov - the problem with that is this: `Foo foo = new Wrapper();
 foo.FooPrint();`

Comment: @GiladGreen What is problem? At case of `Foo foo = new Wrapper();` or `Foo foo = new Foo();` foo.FooPrint(); will output same values: _"Foo"_.

Comment: Ya - but when you use inheritance and override then the `Foo foo = new Wrapper()` will result in `"Haha, only for Bar.foo."` and not like now: `"Foo"`. So this isn't the equivalent for overriding when not inheriting

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a case for this type of behaviour under SRP of SOLID if you needed to separate implementations to maintain the principle (depending on how strictly you are adhering to SOLID ofc).

It's called the Interceptor pattern and used by Mocking libraries such as Moq.

Have a look at the following article on the subject for a good example of how the pattern can be used: [C#: Why Decorate When You Can Intercept](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/06/c-why-decorate-when-you-can-intercept.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of overriding (virtual) methods when you instantiate a class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo a = new Foo();
        a.FooPrint(); // should still print "Foo"

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo.FooPrint(); // should print "Haha, only for Bar.foo."
        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public Action FooPrint = () => Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo foo = new Foo()
    {
        FooPrint = () => Console.WriteLine("Haha, only for Bar.foo.")
    };
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741235/overriding-virtual-methods-when-instantiating-a-class) post explains how to make an override right when you instantiate a class.

However, it uses **Func** which requires a method which contains a return type that isnt void, thats why you'll want to use **Action** instead, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917551/func-delegate-with-no-return-type)

Comment: Take Foo as is, as you have no control to it.

Comment: Ahh my bad then, I guess I'll leave it as an alternative answer which might be of use to someone else..